# Inout arguments are not allowed to alias each other in Swift

Tags: swift

iam getting this two errors when i call a function of my Object

"Inout arguments are not allowed to alias each other"

"Overlapping accesses to 'tim', but modification requires exclusive access; consider copying to a local variable"

I have change the class User to an structur and had to set mutating func and inout parameter but know work anymore.

```
var tim: User = User(username: "Timmi", name: "tim")
        
        tim.friendAnfrage(friend: &tim, appUser: &appInfo.appUser)
        
        var steven: User = User()
        steven.username = "Stevi"
        steven.name = "Steven"
        steven.friendAnfrage(friend: &steven, appUser: &appInfo.appUser)
        
        appInfo.appUser.newFriend(newFriend: &steven,appUser: &appInfo.appUser)
        

struct User: Identifiable{

var id = UUID()
var username: String = ""
var name: String = ""
var password: String = ""
var email: String = ""
var beschreibung: String = ""
var profilBild: UIImage?

var friends = [User]()
var friendAnfrage = [User]()
var anfrageGesendet = [User]()

var feed = [Post]()

mutating func addFriend(friend: inout User,appUser: inout User) {
    friend.friendAnfrage.append(appUser)
    appUser.anfrageGesendet.append(friend)
    
}
mutating func newFriend(newFriend: inout User, appUser: inout User) {
    friends.append(newFriend)
    newFriend.friends.append(appUser)
    
    for i in 0..<friendAnfrage.count {
        if friendAnfrage[i].username == newFriend.username {
            friendAnfrage.remove(at: i)
        }
    }
}
mutating func friendAnfrage(friend: inout User,appUser: inout User) {
    appUser.friendAnfrage.append(friend)
}

mutating func makePost(image: UIImage?,appUser: User) {
    
    guard let image = image else { return }

    let post: Post = Post(ersteller: appUser, image: image, datum: "2022")
    
    feed.append(post)
    
    for i in 0..<friends.count {
        friends[i].feed.append(post)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using inout on friend when it isn't mutated and why is the function friendAnfrage marked as mutating when it isn't changing self (it should be static)?

Comment: when i delte the inout and the mutating beforethe function iam getting this error Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'friend' is a 'let' constant

Comment: i can delete the mutating only before addFriend and FriendAnfragne

Comment: Ok, I didn't pay attention to how you called it. You are passing the same object (tim) as inout to the object itself (tim). This doesn't make any sense. You seem to be confused about how self, mutating and inout works and also confused by your own design and how you want to use this appUser object in relation to how to use other User objects.

Comment: A quick idea without really knowing your app, maybe it would be better if you had one type User for the user of the appr and another type for friends, Friend

Comment: If your design relies so heavily on two-way references consider to use a class, a reference type.

Comment: Or just keep then user id of friends. And have your users as a dictionary [id].